# Unbind checkbox with jQuery keeping functionality

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, bind, checkbox

I'm trying to solve an issue with the simple couple of checkboxes I want to use to show/hide (toggle) the divs but need to keep the checkboxes value, meaning, they cannot use the attribute disabled, because if so, they won't be submitted. So basically what I'm trying is to disable the click on the checkbox that is already checked to avoid clicking the same checkbox and toggle the divs. Only the checkbox that isn't checked should be clickable and by inheritance the div will toggle.
(my problem is with the checkboxes, not the div toggle)

```
<input type="radio" id="cc_email0" name="form[cc_email]" value="0" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="cc_email1" name="form[cc_email]" value="1">

<div id="for_cc_mail0" style="display: block">The div content for 0</div>
<div id="for_cc_mail1" style="display: none">The div content for 1</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
M

Comment: Why don't you just disable them and right before submitting re-enable the checkboxes?

Comment: Why do you need to disable them? If someone clicks the already selected RADIO button, then it'll just make the already visible element visible, thus having no apparent effect.

Comment: @Bob, no, because the attached toggle() in the divs chain behavior. Clicking the same checkbox will toggle the div no matter it is checked or not. That's my problem.

Comment: @Mario gotchya. You can also use the jQuery filter chain .is(':visible') which is one of my favorite tools for this type of situation. simply check if the #for_cc_mail is visible before showing or hiding. pretty much what the answer does, just a little more readable (for me)

Comment: Thanks Bob, I'll keep that as reference. I decided to discard the toggle() and use just show() and hide(). In fact, it was the toggle() that was messing around with what seemed to be a fairly simple thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs are radio buttons not checkboxes. Instead of disabling the inputs, you can try:

```
var $div = $('div');
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
   $div
     .hide()
     .filter('[id="for_'+this.id+'"]')
     .show();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sPy2g/

Note that I have changed the IDs of checkboxes from `cc_email*` to `cc_mail*`.

Comment: Thanks! Need to test it with the markup but seems like this is the solution. I'll get back as soon as tested. thanks

Comment: Hmm... I really need is the disable click or unbind click to work. With your example, that works, I need to change most of what is already done with toggle()

Comment: Ok, figured out how to solve the problem. It's just a matter of changing the toggle()'s I had and do the show() / hide() on the id click. Thanks again for the help!